# How to make indication of mandatory fields and form's validation accessible for screen reader users?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers

When error message will come on validation if use have done something wrong then that error should be read by screen reader?
Any Screen reader compatible, accessible, unobtrusive jquery form validation plugin?

and how user will know which form field is mandatory?

my question is not about to make form with `fieldset`, `legend`, and `label`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard jQuery validation plugin and write your own validate() which collects the errors on submit and displays them in an alert(), rather than relying on showing and hiding divs/spans. alert() is considered to be screen reader compatible according to WebAIM.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0):

Go with using the alert function to display errors. Standard practice appears to be putting a * by any required labels of required form fields.